# TinyMCE, Responsive File Manager Not Showing Up?

Tags: laravel, tinymce, file-manager

I am learning Laravel. Normally my code works on PHP but it's not working on Laravel.

```html
{{Html::script('assets/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js')}}
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "#tinymce",theme: "modern",width: 680,height: 300,
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
            "table contextmenu directionality emoticons paste textcolor responsivefilemanager code"
        ],
        toolbar1: "undo redo | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | styleselect",
        toolbar2: "| responsivefilemanager | link unlink anchor | image media | forecolor backcolor  | print preview code ",
        image_advtab: true ,
        external_filemanager_path:"{{URL::to('/')}}/filemanager/dialog.php",
        filemanager_title:"Responsive Filemanager" ,
        external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "{{URL::to('/')}}/filemanager/plugin.min.js"}
    });
</script>
```

When I delete the `responsivefilemanager` plugin in plugins then it works. How can I fix this?
**I fix this**
responsivefilemanager[plugin] add to tinymce>plugins :) I'm really stupid

Comment: What is not working exactly? Do you see errors? Please give more details.

Comment: If I write them does not seem TinyMCE.

        external_filemanager_path:"{{URL::to('/')}}/filemanager/dialog.php",
        filemanager_title:"Responsive Filemanager" ,
        external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "{{URL::to('/')}}/filemanager/plugin.min.js"}

Comment: I'm really stupid! :) I forgot to dispose of add-ons.